# How to check a date time in current date between two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to detect the existence of a date time in current date between two times. I have fetched a `datetime` data from mysql database, now i want to check if it exists between two time ranges of current date.

```
var date_time = 2020-06-06 18:31:57;
var start = 07:00:00;
var end = 19:00:00;

var form = new Date(start);
var to = new Date(end);
var check = new Date(date_time);
if(check >= form && check <= to){
    alert(check);
}
```

I tried above script not dispaying anything.

Comment: 'form' and 'to' will be invalid dates

Comment: @RahulDwivedi How to make it valid , and solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert dates to timestamp, for example try this

```js
const dateTime = "2020-06-06 18:31:57";
const start = "07:00:00";
const end = "19:00:00";

const [date, time] = dateTime.split(" ");
const startDate = `${date} ${start}`;
const endDate = `${date} ${end}`;

const from = new Date(startDate).getTime();
const to = new Date(endDate).getTime();
const target = new Date(dateTime).getTime();

if (target >= from && target <= to) {
  console.log("in");
}
```

The date constructor accept numbers separated by comas as in my example and as yours accept a string, please take a look to this [post](https://javascript.info/date#creation)

Comment: where should i put my date time and time ranges in it?

Comment: In order to handle the date in your example i updated de answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse your times.

```
var date_time = Date.parse("01 Jan 2020 18:31:57 EST");
```

This will return the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. You can then compare from, to, and the date you are checking.

More info on Date.parse()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse